# AngularJS Unit Testing: WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /.../logo.png (connect ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-mock

Can someone help me figure this out? I've spent a lot of time on it already and I'm spinning my wheels with no resolution.

I'm using Karma/Jasmine with AngularJS to run some unit tests (which use `ngMock` and not `ngMockE2E`). When I run unit tests, the images are not loading, and this is causing a bunch of `WARN` messages to appear in the console (which although not critical, it is undesirable as it may confuse future developers on the project).

I'm using PhantomJS to run my unit tests.

In my `karma.conf.js` file, I am loading the requested *.png files within the dependencies like so:

```
files: [
  //...
  {pattern: 'src/**/*.png', included: false},
  //...
],
```

And I've tried a couple variations of `proxies: {...}` but none of them seem to work. My current attempt is:

```
proxies: {
  '/components/images/': '/base/src/components/images/'
},
```

And the `basePath` is set to:

```
basePath: '../../',
```

Any ideas how to resolve the image locations, or is that not possible sans-ngMockE2E?

Thanks

Comment: What is the route for the `logo.png` image? Have you mapped it in karma?

Comment: @MarcoCl src/components/images/branding/logo.png. Not sure what you mean by mapping... which section of the config is that?

Comment: I thought the path was wrong: `/…/logo.png` instead of `src/components/images/branding/logo.png`, but it's not the case.